# Selenium, workflow for developing test cases

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I would like to hear about your workflow for developing test case for Selenium 2 / webdriver. In JUnit, for example, a developer may start writing a test before he writes a functionality. Then he continuously runs that test against the functionality, possibly in a debugger, modifying code (which gets hot-swapped) to his heart's desires. Is there a more interactive way to write bits and pieces of Selenium code (java) and see immediate results? Do you use Selenium IDE to assist you?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/92250/374512

Right now, I have a bunch of PageObjects and a bunch of test codes that I wrote from scratch. Each time I make a change, I run the test and it has to go from the sequence of logging into the application, navigating a bunch of pages to get to the point of my test. Starting FF profile cold takes at least 5 seconds for the webdriver, and navigation takes another few seconds. How do you code and test a selenium test against a piece of UI functionality in an iterative manner. I want to be able to write a line of code and execute it against a UI in a particular state, a state that took some long sequence of steps to get to.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, there is no fast way to get to a certain state using a browser. Because Selenium tests start from scratch on each execution, there is that start up time to get to the point where you want to test, which makes browser integration testing inherently slow. If there was a way to execute the tests against the UI in a particular state, that would also speed up any regression tests, but I don't believe that's possible or the proper way to test a feature.

I've found it sufficient enough to program the actions in the page object, alongside your development of the UI functionality, and then writing your script to use the actions, similar to what you have been doing. As for when to execute it, I would say run it locally right before you commit to your repo and continuous integration environment. I think of running my tests as a checkpoint, or pre-requisite to committing code.